# C++ basic custom cout printing to consle

Tags: c++, printing, iterator, pretty-print, ostream

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename L>
void print(const T& s, F first, L last)
{
    os << s << " = (\n";

    os << charInput1;
    std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"));
    os << charInput2;

    os << "\n)";
}
```

I'm trying to do a custom cout print. This member function belong to a class `CustomPrinter`, and the `charInput1` and `charInput2` are its private `char` members, which is defined when I construct a custom printer. The `first` and `last` are supposed to be iterators, and `s` is a string.

So for example, given `charInput1` is a `+` sign, and `charInput2` is a period `.`, I would expect the final output to be the following, given a `std::vector<int> = {1, 1, 1}`:

```
(
+1.
+1.
+1.
)
```

But I'm getting

```
(
+1
1
1
.
)
```

So my question is, what else is needed in order to print the given `char` in between each vector element? Is it possible to only use the `std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, /* char here? */)`? Because it seems that this method can only insert strings in between, I need to insert before as well. If not, what can be a better approach? Thanks in advance!

Edit: In my main I have

```
CustomPrinter cp(std::cout, '+', '.');
std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 1};
cp.print("result", v.begin(), v.end()); // function call..
```

Comment: Post a complete, compilable  example of how you call this function.

Comment: @latedeveloper Hi, I've added how the function was called.

Comment: Why have you hard-coded `<int>` as the typename for the `ostream_iterator`? Shouldn't it come from the class template?

Comment: Does it really make sense to have two template parameters for `F` and `L`? Don't they need to be the same iterator type? Maybe you should just have a single template parameter for the element type, and build the iterator type from that. You can then use that same typename for `std::ostream_iterator` as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an ordinary loop:

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename L>
void print(const T& s, F first, L last)
{
    os << s << " = (\n";
    for (auto el = first; el != last; el++) {
        os << charInput1 << *el << charInput2 << "\n";
    }    
    os << ")";
}
```

Actually, you *can* do it using `std::ostream_iterator`, by concatenating your surrounding characters.

```
template<typename T, typename F, typename L>
void print(const T& s, F first, L last)
{

    std::string sep = charInput1 + std::string("\n") + charInput2;
    os << s << " = (\n";
    if (first != last) { // Don't print first prefix and last suffix if the sequence is empty
        os << charInput1;
        std::copy(first, last, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, sep.c_str()));
        os << charInput2;
    }
    os << "\n)";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your edit was really helpful and was what I looked for, in addition to your suggestion on the loop, that of course worked as well.

Comment: Btw, does your compiler complain about `ostream_iterator(std::ostream&, std::string&)`?

Comment: I hadn't tried it, but I now see that `delimiter` has to be `char*`, not `std::string`. I used `.c_str()` to get it.